# Background upload to AWS S3 from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm currently using a service to record WebRTC videos between users. They provide me with a URL to access these recordings.However, I want to move these to Amazon S3 as storage is significantly cheaper. I don't want these videos to go through my Heroku server as that will (I assume) take up far too much memory since the videos can get quite large.

Is there a way to push directly to S3 from a given URL I can't find much help from the S3 docs.

I'm currently hosting a Ruby on Rails server on Heroku. Ideally, I would like this process to happen in a background Sidekiq worker. There would be no browser/client side uploading involved at all.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer isn't the correct one, on the duplicate.  See the answer from Eric Hammond.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is only a storage. It does NOT have any compute capability. You can set up a cron-job or any bash/python script on a nano EC2 server which will do this task. This script will open a URLConnection with your URL --> open a stream --> and start writing to S3 bucket.

Few helping articles: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

https://leonid.shevtsov.me/post/demystifying-s3-browser-upload/